# How to programmatically enable Autostart option for my app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, autostart

How can I enable auto start permission programmatically, please help I have searched a lot ,I want to enable auto-start for device if it is not enabled.Some solutions I have found as below

```
            String manufacturer = Android.OS.Build.Manufacturer;

            Intent intent = new Intent();

            if ("Xiaomi".Equals(manufacturer))
            {
                intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            }
            else if ("oppo".Equals(manufacturer))
            {
                intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
            }

            StartActivity(intent);
```

But in this case it asks the permission every time the app opens(also the auto start option is already enabled).

Please Help me....

Comment: You need to set a user preference that is checked before calling StartActivity. Just save it via a `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Is there any solution to enable auto start with out any user interaction

Comment: No, the user has to to be asked.

Comment: But some apps like whatsapp, amazon could not ask any permission for it.

Comment: apps like Whatsapp are large enough to be pre-whitelisted by the various OEMs. You can review projects like https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter and see that they state the same thing.